# Multiprocessing on Windows breaks

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, traceback

I develop with Python on Linux and have never really seen this sort of problem with Windows. I'm using the `multiprocessing` library to speed up computations, which works very well for me on Linux.

On Windows, however, things don't run as smoothly:

```
 * [INFO] Parsing 1 file using 2 threads

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 170, in <module>
    master = ParsingMaster(parser, list(input_file), output_list, threads=num_threads)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 39, in __init__
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    self.input_process.start()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 342, in main
  File "C:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 104, in start
        self._popen = Popen(self)
self = load(from_parent)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 239, in __init__
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 1370, in load
    dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 162, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    return Unpickler(file).load()
    self.save(obj)
 File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    r aise EOFError
 File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
EOFError
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 40, in dispatcher
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 401, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 458, in __reduce__
    return type(self).from_address, \
AttributeError: type object 'SyncManager' has no attribute 'from_address'
```

I'm testing on both Python 2.6 and 2.7 on Windows 7 and get this same error over and over. Does anybody know what it means?

Comment: Did you read [the platform-specific documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#windows), especially the first restriction?

Comment: Thanks, I just did. I'm only using lists as the arguments for the whole class, so there shouldn't be any pickling errors. I'm not subclassing Process either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are restrictions on Windows, here is the relevant parts to the errors you are seeing:

[Since Windows lacks os.fork() it has a few extra restrictions:](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#windows)

More picklability

> Ensure that all arguments to `Process.__init__()` are picklable. This
>   means, in particular, that bound or unbound methods cannot be used
>   directly as the target argument on Windows — just define a function
>   and use that instead.
>
> Also, if you subclass `Process` then make sure that instances will be
>   picklable when the `Process.start()` method is called.

This means that something that is being passed as an argument to `Process.__init__()` [isn't able to be pickled or unpickled](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) ( a serialization in Python ). What is `SyncManager` it is complaining about not being able to find attributes on that object `AttributeError: type object 'SyncManager' has no attribute 'from_address'`, it is probably your root cause. Can that `SyncManager` object actually be pickled, [does it meet the pickle rules](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)?

If you are running this from the [command line on Windows, you can't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850424/python-multiprocessing-on-python-2-6-win32-xp) either apparently.

Don't do that. Save the code in a file and run it from the file instead, with the command:

```
python myfile.py
```

That will solve your issue.

Comment: I just read that, thanks. Do you know what it means? I'm only using lists as the arguments for the whole class, so there shouldn't be any pickling errors. I'm not subclassing `Process` either.

Comment: I'm running the file via the Windows command line. As for `SyncManager`, I never defined it. It's part of `multiprocessing` as far as I can tell.

Comment: You can't run it in the interactive console, but running the script by typing `python abc.py` in the command line works just fine.

Comment: That's what I meant. I run it via `C:\Python26\python.exe script.py`.

Comment: you saved me from a lot of cr*p :D Thx. I was changing IDEs and nothing seemed to make sense.

Comment: "bound or unbound methods cannot be used directly as the target argument on Windows — just define a function and use that instead." wow, that gets rough if you are trying to port over something that didn't consider this at architecture definition.