# Can a script start a process that starts other child processes using Multiprocessing?

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, subprocess, pickle, traceback

I have not been able to find an answer to this confusing dilemma, and I am wondering if it is the source of an error that is unrecognizable to me. I am running on 64 bit windows 7, and I am currently writing a game where the main process should be able to spawn multiple processes using the Multiprocessing module. Each of those sub-processes then also spawns a single additional process that runs the graphics library using the Multiprocessing module.

When I attempt to run the script (both from IDLE and by running the file from command prompt), I get a traceback that reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\Desktop\Py\split\multiverse.py", line 141, in multiButtonPress
    self.universeList[0].start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 277, in __init__
    dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 199, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 484, in __reduce__
    return type(self).from_address, \
AttributeError: type object 'SyncManager' has no attribute 'from_address'
```

SyncManager is a class found in the multiprocessing library. Is the fact that my subprocess contains an object that is an instance of Process messing with its picklability? If so, is there a way to remedy this without having to completely redesign the system?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670926/multiprocessing-on-windows-breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only limit you'll find on creating grandchildren processes is if your child processes are started with `daemon=True`. As state in the docs for [multiprocessing.Process.daemon](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon):

> Note that a daemonic process is not allowed to create child processes.
>   Otherwise a daemonic process would leave its children orphaned if it
>   gets terminated when its parent process exits. Additionally, these are
>   not Unix daemons or services, they are normal processes that will be
>   terminated (and not joined) if non-daemonic processes have exited.

As long as you do `proc.daemon = False` prior to `proc.start()`, you'll be able to create grandchildren processes in `proc`. The error you're seeing is related to trying to pass a non-picklable object (`multiprocessing.SyncManager`) to your child process. This is a separate problem, and if you need help with that, you should post a new question.

Comment: See, that's what confuses me, I don't believe I have created a SyncManager instance in any of my code. I assumed, since it was also a part of the multiprocessing library, that it was a component of a process?

Comment: Did you create a `multiprocessing.Manager`? That is a child of `SyncManager`

Comment: Whoops! I did not realize SyncManager was a subclass of Manager. Not sure why that one slipped past me. Thanks for your help!