# Compiled Python Multiprocessing Locks CPU

Tags: python, multithreading, py2exe, pyinstaller, python-multithreading

I'm running a scraper program (using the `requests` library) that's using a simplistic threading scheme. Each thread goes to the internet, scrapes some data, and returns a dictionary. The multithreading code (using `multiprocessing` library's `Pool`) which I'm using looks like the following:

```
def get_stats():

    symbols = create_input_list('.\\combined_in.csv')
    pool = Pool(4)
    results = pool.map(return_info, symbols)
    print results

    curr_date_time = datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%y_[%H_%M_%S]')
    out_uri = '.\scraped_info_out_' + curr_date_time + '.csv'
    create_output_file(out_uri, results)
```

This works GREAT as a script running in powershell, but not so well when compiled to an exe. I used py2exe initially, which created the exe just fine, but when run opens a blank terminal, locks the whole computer, spawns about 10 processes that I can see in task manager, and eventually has to be manually rebooted. The py2exe script is similarly simple and looks like:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['scraper.py'])
```

Thinking that py2exe might just not play nice with the multiprocessing library, I also tried pyInstaller, with the same result. Additionally, I do have the blocker on the main function call as follows.

```
if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    get_stats()
```

Is there a simple trick that I'm missing for when compiling with the multiprocessing library? I'm trying to figure out why it would work fine as a script but break so hard as an exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant answer about py2exe ... but pyinstaller this is a known problem with a well documented work around (that has always worked for me)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27694505/541038

provides a good overview of the problem and the solution

Comment: The addition of `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` to the `__main__` if worked PERFECTLY. Thank you so much!