# multiprocessing object has no attribute 'forking'

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, fork, attributeerror

I am running into the same problems as described in: [PyInstaller-built Windows EXE fails with multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944558/pyinstaller-built-windows-exe-fails-with-multiprocessing)

When trying to add the proposed codelines (see below) I get the following AttributeError:

class _Popen(multiprocessing.forking.Popen):

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'forking'

Also my IDE (PyCharm) indicates "Cannot find reference '_MEIPASS' in 'sys.py'.
What am I missing here (running Python 2.7)?

```
class _Popen(multiprocessing.forking.Popen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
            os.putenv('_MEIPASS2', sys._MEIPASS)
        try:
            super(_Popen, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        finally:
            if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
                os.unsetenv('_MEIPASS2')


class Process(multiprocessing.Process):
    _Popen = _Popen
```

Comment: You need to `import multiprocessing.forking`, did you?!

Comment: Indeed. Thanks Antti. Just 'import multiprocessing' was not enough......