# How to create a portable executable that works with 3.6.6 / 3.7.0 and multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to create a portable executable that works with 3.6.6 / 3.7.0 and multiprocessing. I have tried both cx_freeze (which didn't work at all for 3.7.0 even tho they said it's supported) and Nuitka, I have not gotten multiprocessing to work on any of them.

cx_freeze got weird issues that has multiple fixes, but none have worked for me.

Nuitka is the one I have had the least issues with, but I haven't gotten it to work with multiprocessing.

Note, Python 3.6.6 or 3.7.0 and Windows, no py2exe for 2.x or for linux.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you calling `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` where you import that module?

Comment: I have not, I will try that!

Answer (score -1):

I use [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/). It does not support 3.7, but is fine for 3.3-3.6

If you are having issues with multiprocessing when using pyinstaller, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944558/pyinstaller-built-windows-exe-fails-with-multiprocessing) stackoverflow question may be of help.

Comment: I believe I already tried this compiler too, as I went thru all of the top 10 on google one by one as none worked. I will double check tho!