# multiprocessing pyinstaller - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'parent_pid=12004'

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-multiprocessing

i have a simple script that uses multiprocessing to stress the CPU cores.

```py
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep
import math 

class StressTestManager:

    def stressCpu(self,seconds):
        multiprocessing.freeze_support()
        processes = []
        for _ in range (multiprocessing.cpu_count()):
            sleep(0.1)
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target =self._generateCpuLoad)
            p.start()
            processes.append(p)
        sleep(seconds)
        for process in processes:
            process.terminate()
    

    def _generateCpuLoad(self):
        while True:
            a = math.sqrt(64 * 32)     
            
            
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    StressTestManager().stressCpu(10)
```

this works fine, but when i convert it to an exe file using pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console  "...FolderName/stress_test_manager.py"
```

and run the file, i get this error, which prints out for each Process i run

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stress_test_manager.py", line 38, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'parent_pid=12004'
[21920] Failed to execute script 'stress_test_manager' due to unhandled exception!
```

i'm using Python 3.11.5

i've tried to use --onefile and --onefolder, it didn't change anything, i added `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` and using a local Process class as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944558/pyinstaller-built-windows-exe-fails-with-multiprocessing) i still get the same error.

Comment: What is line 38 of stress_test_manager.py?

Comment: @mkrieger1 the whole file is 26 lines, that line 38 is not inside my file, 
if you notice, it's written "line 38, in <module>" the problem is inside a module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up using [py2exe](https://github.com/py2exe/py2exe) instead, it works just fine with multiprocessing.

it's not exactly a technical solution, but it's a solution to work around this error.