# Python multiprocessing on windows: Can't pickle SyncManager, works on linux

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am trying to do a simple multiprocessing with shared queue:

```
def RunInParallel(self, states):
    res_q = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
    processes = []
    for s in states:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=StateWorker,
                                    args=(self, s, res_q))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    # Wait for all the processes to complete
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    results = [res_q.get() for _ in processes]
    for result in results:
        if result != 0:
            return result

    return 0
```

The StateWorker is outside the class at module scope:

```
def StateWorker(cmd_obj, state, result_queue):
    result_queue.put(cmd_obj.RunState(state))
```

This works totally fine on linux, but on windows fails with following error: (It's Python 2.7.5)

> Can't pickle class 'multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager': it's not
>   found as multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager

I have tried some solutions from other threads like subclassing SyncManager etc, none of them worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiprocessing on Windows breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670926/multiprocessing-on-windows-breaks)

Comment: I have already looked at this, tried those solutions, and am not running the code through console. If I subclass SyncManager, error changes to can't pickle Thread.lock, that was the first error I solved by using SyncManager, so it's like a cycle now.